# Subversion: is it possible to backup only the delta since the last backup?

Tags: svn, backup-strategies

Does someone here know if it is possible to backup only the part of a
subversion reposiotory that has changed since the last backup (that is:
the delta)?

Practically, that could be something like doing a full backup every
midnight, and a delta every hour. If then a crash occured say at 11:07,
one would have to use last midnights full backup and apply all deltas
on it, thus only seven minutes would be lost.

Also, if this should be possible, can that be made in a "hot-backup"
mode (if that is the correct term for it), that is, while other users
are operating, especially checking in, on the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is certainly possible. You can do an `svnadmin dump -r(from_rev) --incremental` to dump all changes from revision *(from_rev)* onwards (if you omit the `--incremental`, the contents of the *(from_rev)* revision will be dumped fully). All commits are atomic, so you can do a hot-backup this way - commits that are still in progress will not be in this dump but in the next one.

Comment: This is the approach I'm taking. I'm writing a python script to dump/load, that will be run every hour or so. The only downside to this approach is that it only captures commits (or other rev changes), it won't capture changes to a repository's config (or other non-revision changing events).

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into using svnsync on a post-commit hook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler and probably almost as efficient to use rsync. rsync also has the benefit that it can do more things, other than the repository.

Comment: Especially with the fsfs filesystem, rsync works pretty nicely for this. It's not so nice in hot-backup mode though, as all lockfiles and intermediate stuff is also rsync'd.